# Quirks working around "number stored as text"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, format, vlookup

I want to preface this with I do not have direct query access. I must work through this program that we build reports in. I'll leave my opinions about its quirks aside. I cannot micromanage the data when I query/download. I can only pull as it is stored and let the program spit something out into excel.

I am working around the annoyance of excel storing numbers as text, but only sometimes. When I import my table it stores our customer numbers as "number stored as text". The problem is that I need to perform vlookups on this and it isn't consistent about storing a number or number as text. (If you know a way to make it stop that I'm open to suggestions).

I have gotten around this by using:

```
=vlookup(text(A2,"0000000000"),range,#)
```

However while tweaking my report all of a sudden this has stopped working consistently. The formula I have is as follows

```
=if(C3>0,vlookup(text(C3,"0000000000"),range,#,false),vlookup(text(A3,"0000000000"),range,#,false))
```

I have also completely removed any text functions from the vlookup and it still does not work. I suspect it's because column while column C is importing normally column A is a number stored as text. Is there a way to put the text function on the range reference?

My setup (in case it's relevant) is that I query some sales data, put it into a "sales" tab. Query some lost sales data put it into a "lost sales" tab. I then build tables based on groupings of customers that is custom defined. This custom definition is the key I am trying to pull onto both of these tables so that I can do my pivots and reporting on the defined customer group.

The table I'm referencing in the range portion of the lookup is on it's own "options" tab and is a static list of customer number, name, and ID.

I'm looking for troubleshooting regarding the above. And any advice regarding dealing with vlookups and inconsistent formatting without manually converting every download (thousands of lines). Would index-match eliminate this problem? Are there other better workarounds for this problem?

THank you!!

Comment: You can do two VLOOKUP, one with the TEXT and the other without: `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TEXT(),,,),VLOOKUP(withoutTEXT,,,))`

Comment: Better use INDEX/MATCH like: `{=INDEX([output range],MATCH(A2&"",[lookuprange]&"",0))}`... always use INDEX/MATCH (it also is MUCH faster) :P

Comment: @DirkReichel what is the purpose of putting A2&"" instead of just A2? Does this force a certain format or something?

Comment: @Mel `A2&""` will be A2 as a text value... so the number `5` will become the text `5` while the text `5` will remain unchanged... also `A2*1` and `[lookuprange]*1` is possible to change everything to numbers... (will work as long as there are no leading `0`'s;)

Comment: @DirkReichel okay that makes sense. the scale I'm on right now doesn't really matter. But is there any reason to use A2&"" vs text(A2)? Or are these just synonyms that have no variation on impact?

Comment: @Mel there is no real difference... on bigger tables `&""` will be slight faster as the change is done at a lower level than `TEXT` (which also runs some extra code which offers special formattings)... while `TEXT` is more obvious for other ppl (your formulas are easier to understand)

Comment: @DirkReichel  Okay thanks! I'll use this as an opportunity to force myself off of vlookup and start using index-match. If all else fails I'll try out ScottCraner's idea.

Comment: @ScottCraner that never occurred to me. And it really should have. ha Thanks!